# How to enable indentation guides only for HTML files in VS Code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, indentation

I'm not fond of the indentation guides in VS Code and find them distracting, except in HTML where they are necessary.

I know that I can disable them for all files by adding `"editor.guides.indentation": false` to settings.json, but is there any way of disabling them for all files but HTML files?

Answer (score -1):

In [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"editor.guides.indentation": false,
"[html]": { // for multiple languages, ex. "[html][css][javascript]"
    "editor.guides.indentation": true,
},
```

See also https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings.